# Using a Recursive DVWP query, can I retrieve the site name?

Tags: data-view-web-part, 2007

I have successfully created a DVWP which queries all lists in my subsites and returns the correct columns using the following selectcommand:

```
<View>
      <Webs Scope="Recursive"></Webs>
      <View>
        <ViewFields>
          <FieldRef Name="Development_x0020_Status" />
          <FieldRef Name="Title" />
          <FieldRef Name="FileDirRef" />
          <FieldRef Name="ID" />
          <FieldRef Name="StreamName" />
        </ViewFields>
      </View>
      <Query>
        <OrderBy>
          <FieldRef Name="StreamName" Ascending="TRUE" />
          <FieldRef Name="Title" Ascending="TRUE" />
        </OrderBy>
      </Query>
    </View>
```

One of the things i would now like to be able to do is group the results by the site that the item is located, much the same as a CWQP does group by . The query currently returns the webId, but I cannot see how to return the site name. How can i return this value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do this by accessing the Project properties.  (List properties are also available.)  See my blog post called [Project and List Properties Available from CAML](http://mdasblog.wordpress.com/2009/02/26/10065/).

M.

Comment: Thankyou. Worked perfectly first time.

Comment: You bet. Glad to help.